# efficiancy of indexing frequently update collection in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I am newbie with MongoDB so my questions might be trivial ... I want to allow my users to upload their address book. the document have the following structure

```
{ 
"_id" : "56f29ecc2a00001800dbdf54", 
"contacts" : [
    {
        "name" : "John", 
        "phoneNumber" : [
            "+18144040000"
        ]
    }, 
    {
        "name" : "Andrew ", 
        "phoneNumber" : [
            "+14129123456"
        ]
    }
]
}
```

I would like to run search by phone number in order to find useres with mutual contacts
i.e

```
{"contacts.phoneNumber":"+14129123456"}
```

my question is - **will it be efficient to add this index**

```
db.addresses.createIndex( { "contacts.phoneNumber": 1 }, { unique: false }, {background: true} )
```

considering the fact that the user will frequently update his address book from his phone which overrides the current data or insert new one. this upload is a single document with an array of contacts each hold an array of phone numbers .
each upload/update will contain hundreds/thousands of records ?

Comment: It depends on your non functional requirement. Does the upload process is sync online process or batch process as you have mentioned that upload would have 1000s of documents?

Comment: @notionquest thank you for pointing that, I just edited my question elaborating that point . each user have a single document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your index make sense. Reg the efficiency there is a trade off between read and write. Typically, user interface is expected to respond quickly for any search (i.e. read). So, creating the index on specific field is inevitable. On that basis, indexing on "phone number" is fine considering that the use case required a search or query on phone number directly.

Indexing the document would degrade the write performance. However, this particular index wouldn't degrade the write performance drastically. Having said that if it takes more time, you may need to reconsider the UI design to have progress bar for upload which is a typical UI design for any large uploads.

Also, you can check about the write concern option available in MongoDB. You can configure the write concern whether you are expecting the acknowledgement from the drive or not.

If you consider going with write concern without acknowledgement, it would give you better write performance. However, most of the applications expect acknowledgement on writes to ensure that the write is successful.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/write-concern/

Comment: Thanks , will is degrade the write performance although the index build is marked with background = true ?

Comment: Background = true - means when you create the index first time, the index creation process would run in the background and wouldn't block the whole database. When you do atomic insert/update, the index gets updated immediately.  https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-creation/

Comment: The index looks ok although it is on an array and not single value ?

Comment: Yes, you can create non-unique index on array field. This is absolutely fine. Look at the ratings index here - https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-multikey/ ... db.inventory.createIndex( { ratings: 1 } )